# Dart - How can I handle multiple socket responses?

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart, socket.io

I need to constantly query to a server socket four commands stored in the List pollingCommands:

Command1, Command2, Command3 and Command4 which returns Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 and Answer4 respectively.

My approach has been the following:

```
 Socket.connect(ip, port).then((Socket sock) {
  _socket = sock;
  _socket.listen(
    dataHandler,
    onError: errorHandler,
    onDone: doneHandler,
    cancelOnError: false,
  );
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
    if (isComplete) {
      _socket.write(
        Command.pollingQuery(pollingCommands[pollingCycle]),
      );
    }
  });
}).catchError((Object error) {
  print("ERROR !");
});
```

This is the data handler

```
  void dataHandler(data) {
    result = String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
    if (isComplete) {
      isComplete = false;
      //Some action
      if (pollingCycle == pollingCommands.length - 1) {
        pollingCycle = 0;
        isComplete = true;
      } else {
        pollingCycle++;
        isComplete = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

This approach is working for me if the timer is greater than 500ms but im not geting it to work with higher frequency as the commands does not correspond to their answer.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a timer? You can send the next command directly in `dataHandler()`.

Comment: Would't that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, but isn't that exactly what you wanted? _"I need to constantly query to a server socket..."_